# How to temporarily stop refreshing Primefaces line chart when zooming

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF/Primefaces p:chart to display a dynamic line chart that updates periodically (e.g. with an interval of 3 seconds) via p:poll tag according to the real-time data, and the zoom property is set to true. Now, the problem is that I want the chart to temporarily stop updating when I zoom and resume when I double-click to reset zoom. However, the updated chart always override the zoomed chart that I am watching. How can I configure the chart to let it stop refreshing when zooming?

Comment: The cart is not refreshing itself, the poll is. Solution stop the poll (read the documentation)

Comment: Yes, I can add two buttons to start and stop the p:poll manually, which means the user can stop the poll, zoom and then start the poll after zooming. But is there an implementation that is more convenient to the user? That is the p:poll is automatically stopped when the user is zooming and is automatically started after the user finishing zooming.

Comment: Starting zooming is easy to detect... There is a 'zoom event' in the chart afaik. 'Stopping' zooming (not in your original question) is rather difficult to detect (you cannot check the user not doing anything, unless you user some timeout after each zoom event and reset it if there is a new zoom event). But what if the user is not zooming but panning... So a 'start updating again' button would not be to strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, it turns out that both Zoom and ResetZoom have events, so I can bind javascript functions to these events in order to stop and start p:poll.

Let me share my solution as the following code snippet.

index.xhtml

```
<h:form id="dashboardForm">
    <p:poll interval="3" update="chart"  process="@this"  global="false"  ignoreAutoUpdate="true" widgetVar="chartpoll"/>
    <p:chart id="chart" type="line" model="#{chartView.zoomModel}" style="height:300px;" widgetVar="chart" responsive="true"/>
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function lineChartExtender() {
    $('#dashboardForm\\:chart').bind('jqplotZoom', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, plot, cursor){
        PF('chartpoll').stop();
    });
    $('#dashboardForm\\:chart').bind('jqplotResetZoom', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, plot, cursor){
        PF('chartpoll').start();
    });
}
</script>
```

ChartView.java

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
model.setZoom(true);
model.setExtender("lineChartExtender");
```